# What is a "domain" in the maximum-minimum principle?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The **maximum-minimum principle** says that

*A harmonic function on a domain cannot attain its maximum or its minimum unless it is constant.*

Here is my **question**:

> If we restrict our attention in
>   ${\mathbb R}^2$ or ${\mathbb R}^3$,
>   what's the hypothesis for the domain?
>   (bounded? closed? open?)

According to the proof of this principle, it seems that the domain is open. I could not find the context which may indicate the properties of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_%28mathematical_analysis%29) is usually defined as an open connected set.

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum principle is stated in your book exactly as you stated, then what the book means by a domain is open, connected, **bounded** set. For the maximum principle is not valid for unbounded domains. But I must say usually domain means just open connected set. Often times "nonempty" is also included in the definition.